# Color themes gallery somewhere for emacs?

Tags: emacs

I remmbemer there a website the had a list of color-themes for emacs. Can't seem to find it. It was for the old `color-theme` package.

Also, what about new color themes in emacs24 - is there a gallery of those somewhere? (I've had to google for these - only found 3).

Comment: Good question. Most themes can be found by searching the package list for "color-theme", but it'd be great to see them all displayed somewhere.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I created a site where I try to list screeshots of all the Emacs themes out there.

https://emacsthemes.com/

Answer (score 13):

Here is one theme gallery for emacs 24:

http://zazez.com/emacs24_themes/emacs.html

UPDATE: Since the link above is dead, here is another gallery:

https://github.com/owainlewis/emacs-color-themes

There are also many other emacs themes with previews on Github:

https://github.com/search?q=emacs+theme

Comment: Great stuff thanks! (Almost perfect, if it was a little bigger in size haha).

Comment: Link appears dead [25 Jul 2013].

Answer (score 6):

Found another one today, you might want to check http://vijaykiran.com/projects/emacs-themes-gallery/ (hopefully it will be maintained)

---

**EDIT:** Another great discovery: https://github.com/emacs-jp/replace-colorthemes

Full gallery at https://github.com/emacs-jp/replace-colorthemes/blob/master/screenshots.md